# Covariance Matrix using For Loops Python

Tags: python

I am trying to develop a code to compute a covariance matrix of a dataset using For Loops instead of Numpy. The code I have so far generates an error:

```
def cov_naive(X):
    """Compute the covariance for a dataset of size (D,N) 
    where D is the dimension and N is the number of data points"""
    D, N = X.shape
    ### Edit the code below to compute the covariance matrix by iterating over the dataset.
    covariance = np.zeros((D, D))
    mean = np.mean(X, axis=1)
    for i in range(D):
        for j in range(D):
            covariance[i,j] += (X[:,i] - mean[i]) @ (X[:,j] - mean[j])

    return covariance/N
```

I am trying to perform the below test to validate that it works:

```
# Let's first test the functions on some hand-crafted dataset.
X_test = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
expected_test_mean = np.array([1., 4.]).reshape(-1, 1)
expected_test_cov = np.array([[2/3., 2/3.], [2/3.,2/3.]])

print('X:\n', X_test)
print('Expected mean:\n', expected_test_mean)
print('Expected covariance:\n', expected_test_cov)

np.testing.assert_almost_equal(mean(X_test), expected_test_mean)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(mean_naive(X_test), expected_test_mean)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(cov(X_test), expected_test_cov)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(cov_naive(X_test), expected_test_cov)
```

and get the following error:

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 7 decimals
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-6a6498089109> in <module>()
 12 
 13 np.testing.assert_almost_equal(cov(X_test), expected_test_cov)
---> 14 np.testing.assert_almost_equal(cov_naive(X_test), expected_test_cov)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the actual matrix values, so that we can see if it's a numeric error (small fractional difference) or an algorithmic issue? (values will appear very different)

Comment: @BarakItkin the actual matrix is very large and the data are image pixels of faces. It would be hard to share the actual data, but the covariance function, if it works in a simple dataset here, it should work on the original dataset. Why do you ask, do you think my script for covariance is correct?

Comment: @BarakItkin if it helps, this is where I got the data:
image_shape = (64, 64)
# Load faces data
dataset = fetch_olivetti_faces('./')
faces = dataset.data.T

print('Shape of the faces dataset: {}'.format(faces.shape))
print('{} data points'.format(faces.shape[1]))

Comment: Generally when writing this sort of code, it's easiest to test it with your eyes to see if you are way off or if this is a numeric issue. You can also extract a random 4x4 sample at a fixed location from both matrices (use the same location) and compare that.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake lies in that line

```
mean = np.mean(X, axis=1)
```

it should be:

```
mean = np.mean(X, axis=0)
```

as you are computing the mean over the columns (ie dataset Dimensionality)